# Ways to switch language on website with pure JS

Tags: javascript, css, translate

I don't know which is the best way to follow to translate my page, my first idea is to when i switch to language like english then remove Body and insert other body with english language, second idea is like below:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.toggle');
const currentLang = document.querySelectorAll('.current-lang');
const hiddenLang = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden-lang');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  currentLang.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.remove('current-lang');
    item.classList.add('hidden-lang');
  });

  hiddenLang.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.remove('hidden-lang');
    item.classList.add('current-lang');
  });



});
```

```css
.current-lang {
  display: block;
}

.hidden-lang {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="current-lang">Una pizza italiano unica e adorabile con pesto di pomodoro, prosciutto, pancetta e pepe.</p>
<br>
<p class="hidden-lang">A unique and adorable Italian Pizza with tomato pesto, ham, bacon and pepper.</p>


<button class="toggle">Change</button>
```

If you have more simple ways and efficient i will appreciate it if share it with me!

Comment: I think other libraries use an array of strings for each language. Easier to manage translations and more flexible than hardcoding to html

Comment: Best to have a different URL with entirely different pages for each language. Look at how wikipedia manages multiple languages

Comment: @ZachJensz Yes i thought that but i have to pay two domains i think..

Comment: No you just have a subdomain for each, or have them under a different path

Comment: There are good examples on the web, see https://phrase.com/blog/posts/step-step-guide-javascript-localization/ and https://www.javacodegeeks.com/step-by-step-guide-to-javascript-localization.html.

Comment: @ZachJensz Oh okay, do you have any example to understand it better? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the [lang attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang)

```js
const 
  btn   = document.querySelector('.toggle')
, langs = ['it','en-GB']
  ;

var currentLang = langs.indexOf( document.body.lang);
 
btn.addEventListener('click', () => 
  {
  currentLang = ++currentLang % langs.length
  document.body.lang = langs[currentLang]
  });
```

```css
body:lang(it)    *:not(:lang(it)) ,
body:lang(en-GB) *:not(:lang(en-GB))
  {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<body lang="it">
  
  <p lang="it">Una pizza italiano unica e adorabile con pesto di pomodoro, prosciutto, pancetta e pepe.</p>
  <p lang="en-GB">A unique and adorable Italian Pizza with tomato pesto, ham, bacon and pepper.</p>


  <button class="toggle">Change</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this is good idea BUT i don't want to be visible in inspect element, as you will see when you inspect it you will see the hidden element so i don't like it so much :/

Comment: @Crowman how is this different from your own proposed solution?

Comment: @marco-a It's not different but its better aprroach of my solution

Comment: @Crowman that's what motivated my answer, but obviously it's not even worth a plus... _(even if it respects the SEO rules on languages)_

Answer (score 0):

##### There are multiple approaches to this, but if you don't want to use any framework or library whatsoever, then:

You could set a global variable:

```js
let language = "english"
```

And an i18n.js file containing all texts in your application.

```js
export function useText(language) { // language would be the current string
  switch(language) {
    case "english":
    return useEnglish()
    case "italian":
    return useItalian()
  }
}

const useEnglish = () => ({
  pizzaText: "A unique and adorable Italian Pizza with tomato pesto, ham, bacon and pepper",
})

const useItalian = () => ({
  pizzaText: "Una pizza italiano unica e adorabile con pesto di pomodoro, prosciutto, pancetta e pepe",
})
```

And to get the text you would only need to do the following:

```js
const text = useText(currentLanguage).pizzaText
```

And you could set it to the html using whatever javascript method you normally use.

This would mean that all of your text in pages would need to consume this function, and every time you add some text you would need to extend this file.

It will help you organize and know easier if a translation is wrong or if there is a translation missing.

Comment: This won't work, unless you add some kind of observer mechanism. `useText(currentLanguage).pizzaText` will literally return a constant string that won't change.

Comment: Of course! If you change current language then you would reload the texts.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer then, I suggest you add the 'reload' mechanism to your answer.